# Get directories only with glob pattern using pathlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, glob, pathlib

I want to use `pathlib.glob()` to find directories with a specific name pattern (`*data`) in the current working dir. I don't want to explicitly check via `.isdir()` or something else.

#### Input data

This is the relevant listing with three folders as the expected result and one file with the same pattern but that should be part of the result.

```
ls -ld *data
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4,0K  9. Sep 10:22 2021-02-11_68923_data/
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4,0K  9. Sep 10:22 2021-04-03_38923_data/
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4,0K  9. Sep 10:22 2022-01-03_38923_data/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0  9. Sep 10:24 2011-12-43_3423_data
```

#### Expected result

```
[
    '2021-02-11_68923_data/', 
    '2021-04-03_38923_data/',
    '2022-01-03_38923_data/'
]
```

#### Minimal working example

```
from pathlib import Path
cwd = Path.cwd()

result = cwd.glob('*_data/')
result = list(result)
```

That gives me the 3 folders **but** also the file.

Also tried the variant `cwd.glob('**/*_data/')`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trailing path separator certainly should be respected in `pathlib.glob` patterns. This is the expected behaviour in shells on all platforms, and is also [how the glob module works](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#module-glob):

> If the pattern is followed by an os.sep or os.altsep **then files will not match**.

However, there is a bug in pathlib that was fixed in [bpo-22276](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/10349), and merged in [Python-3.11.0rc1](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3110rc1/) (see [what's new: pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#pathlib)).

In the meantime, as a work-around you can use the glob module to get the behaviour you want:

```
$ ls -ld *data
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Sep  9 22:45 2022-01-03_38923_data
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Sep  9 22:44 2021-04-03_38923_data
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Sep  9 22:44 2021-02-11_68923_data
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 Sep  9 22:45 2011-12-43_3423_data
```

```py
>>> import glob
>>> res = glob.glob('*_data')
>>> print('\n'.join(res))
2022-01-03_38923_data
2011-12-43_3423_data
2021-02-11_68923_data
2021-04-03_38923_data
```

```py
>>> res = glob.glob('*_data/')
>>> print('\n'.join(res))
2022-01-03_38923_data/
2021-02-11_68923_data/
2021-04-03_38923_data/
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't fit to my example. You don't use a name pattern for the folder.

Comment: @buhtz Okay, I have updated my answer to match your example. The name pattern works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`glob` is insufficient here. From the filesystem's perspective, the directory's name really is "2021-02-11_68923_data", not "2021-02-11_68923_data/". Since glob only looks at names, it cannot differentiate between "regular" files and directories, and you'd have to add some additional check, such as `isdir` that you mentioned.

Comment: But why can I do `glob('/**/*`)` which gives me all directories only?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as you need to check using "is_dir()":

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path("./").rglob("*"):
    if path.is_dir():
        print(path)
```